# Finding 4th Moment of a Random Variable.

Tags: expectation

In an attempt to derive something, I have come to a point where I need to know what the following can be simplified to. It looks to me that I am looking for the 4th moment of ''y''. I am just not sure how to go about this.

$$E\space[\space(\space\sum_{i=1}^N (\space y_i^2\space)\space)^2\space]= \space ?$$

For my problem, the following relationship is valid$$ 
E\space[\sum_{i=1}^N\space y_i^2 \space] = \space N\sigma^2 $$

Note that: $$y_i \sim \space N(0,\sigma^2)  $$

Comment: Are these $Y_i$ independent?

Comment: Yes, they are independent.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a fourth moment it's actually a second (non-central) moment of the chi square.

Up to a constant the sum $\sum(y_i^2)$ is a chi-squared random variable with $N$ degress of freedom.  So up to a constant this is the second non-central moment of a chi square with $N$ degrees of freedom.

Look here for the formula for the second non-central moment: 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi-squared_distribution#Noncentral_moments

Comment: I should make the correction. The sum runs from 1 to N. Not 0 to N. 
So there are N number of random variables yi. And they are all independent.
So now that I have made the correction, the sum runs from 1 to N. 
So it is indeed $$ N \sigma^2 $$ as mentioned.

Thank you for your response. 
I will have to look more into chi-squared r.v. before I can get to a conclusion

Comment: Thank you for your response. 
When you say $$ X = \sum Y_i^2  $$ then E[X] is not 0.
It is as I said, $$ N\sigma^2 $$

Comment: Yes sorry, it's the second non-central moment of a chi-squared, there's a formula for that on the chi square wiki page.  I updated my answer to fix the mistake.

Comment: Based on the wikipedia page, the non-central moment of a chi-squared random variable with k degrees of freedom is:

$$ E[X^m] \space = \space k(k+2)(k+4)...(k+2m-2) $$
 
We are interested in second non-central moment of the chi-square which means m=2 in the above equation and since our sum runs from 1 to N, there are N degrees of freedom, just as you suggested. This makes k=N.

The above expression reduces down to:

$$ E[X^2] \space = \space N(N+2)  $$

The original question that was asked therefore equals:

$$E[(\space\sum_{i=1}^N \space(y_i^2))^2\space]= \space N(N+2)$$

Comment: Well no be careful because $\sum y_i^2$ only equals a chi square up to a constant.  You have to divide by $\sigma^2$ or something like that to get each of the $y_i^2$ a standard normal.

Comment: Well, I can't seem to figure out exactly what that something is that I need to divide.